# Not understand test flight beta testing

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

now i am using test flight for testing my application.Testflight said from next month onwards standard test flight is not available.SO i have some doubt on this please clarify

-Standard test flight is available for already existing apps or not?If available can i release new build?

-How can i test the ios 7 apps with test flight beta testing.

-Apple saying,each prerelease version expires after 30 days.So after 30 days can i test downloaded app?

-Suppose i released build A and installed in some devices and after 10 days again i released build B and installed on some other devices.Both are working or only latest Build B is working?

-Each internal tester can test the app in 10 devices,So how we can register that devices.

-Each version we have to wait for beta app review for external testers?

If any information is useful for me please post except these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -Standard test flight is available for already existing apps or not?If available can i release new build?

The original TestFlight is being shut down. Apple's TestFlight is the new TestFlight and you can use it with existing apps.

> -How can i test the ios 7 apps with test flight beta testing.

You can't. TestFlight is iOS 8 only.

> -Apple saying,each prerelease version expires after 30 days.So after 30 days can i test downloaded app?

This means that the build expires in 30 days. You have to keep submitting new builds for your testers.

I find this good way to keep your testers really up to date and up to the task. In contrast, if build didn't expire, the beta testers could stick to the old versions and eventually become a burden (irrelevant bug reports, etc.).

> -Suppose i released build A and installed in some devices and after 10 days again i released build B and installed on some other devices.Both are working or only latest Build B is working?

I think the old build A will continue working for the aforementioned 30 days when you submit the new build. You simply can't revert back to it. I'm not absolutely sure though, but there is a transition time for beta testers to update to the new version.

> -Each internal tester can test the app in 10 devices,So how we can register that devices.

I haven't had any internal testers but my guess is that the usual way: add the devices from the developer portal.

> -Each version we have to wait for beta app review for external testers?

Yes. However, if the new builds have no major modifications they might not need to wait for the review process. This is being asked when you submit consecutive builds.

I think there is a chance of review even with small updates, but I haven't seen any. I've had new builds ready to distribute within the same hour every time I submit a minor update.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, the All-New TestFlight Beta Testing service was launched inside of iTunes Connect.

Here's What's New:

Invite up to 1,000 external testers using just their email address
Easy to use TestFlight iOS app available on the App Store
No need to keep track of UDIDs or provisioning profiles
Beta testing directly inside of iTunes Connect without the need of the TestFlight SDK
Learn more »

With the new version of the TestFlight service available inside of iTunes Connect, we are also informing you that TestFlightapp.com will no longer be available as of 2/26/2015.

To prepare for the TestFlightapp.com closure, we recommend that you export all of your current testers so you can import them directly into the new TestFlight Beta Testing service.

How to export testers from TestFlightapp.com

Sign in to the TestFlight Dashboard at testflightapp.com
Navigate to the "People" tab
Check mark the teammates you would like to export
Open the "Actions" menu on the right side of the teammates list
Select "Export Contact Info" to download the exported CSV file

How to import testers into the new TestFlight Beta Testing

Sign in to iTunes Connect at itunesconnect.apple.com
Click "My Apps"
Select the app you want to enable for beta testing
Enter the "Prerelease" tab and select "External Testers"
Click the plus sign to add new external testers
Use the "Import File" from the "Add New External Testers" page to upload the exported CSV file

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: i think this answer was not helpful for me

Comment: Why this is not helpful to you? Above context clear your all doubts.If you have any confusion tell me.

Answer (score 1):

-Standard test flight is available for already existing apps or not?If available can i release new build?
**Standard Test flight app is completely shut down. You cannot use it anymore.**

-How can i test the ios 7 apps with test flight beta testing.
**Testflight beta testing is not available for iOS 7 apps.**

-Apple saying,each prerelease version expires after 30 days.So after 30 days can i test downloaded app?
**Yes, you can continue testing already downloaded app. 30 days is the active period for downloading app.**

-Suppose i released build A and installed in some devices and after 10 days again i released build B and installed on some other devices.Both are working or only latest Build B is working?
**Both will continue to work but after uploading release B, build A will be deactivated for downloading. Only latest uploaded builds will be active.**

-Each internal tester can test the app in 10 devices,So how we can register that devices.
**When you accept the invitation from any device, the device gets registered.**

-Each version we have to wait for beta app review for external testers?
**Yes, you need to wait for approval then only you can distribute app to external testers.**